# Visual Studio 2022 free certificate problem. "cannot import key file " how to fix

Tags: containers, certificate, key

Several years ago, I used Visual Studio to create a desktop app. I deployed it to friends.   Now I want to refine it.  I downloaded the free Visual Studio 2022 and opened the SLN for my previous code.   I get  "Importing key file "SlideShow_2_TemporaryKey."

"Cannot import the following key file: SlideShow_2_TemporaryKey.pfx. The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the following key container name: VS_KEY_F4D87CD9FC439D66."

This makes no sense to me.   How do I do this?

I have no memory of any certificate and do not know how go import it.